# virsh net-define error: this function is not supported

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, virt-manager, virsh

I'm trying to create a simple network using the following xml:

```
<network>
  <name>net-bridge</name>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="virbr0"/>
</network>
```

Resulting in this error:

```
gthost ~ # virsh net-define net-bridge.xml 
error: Failed to define network from net-bridge.xml
error: this function is not supported by the connection driver: virNetworkDefineXML
```

Similar error messages related to network creation if I try creating a domain with "virsh define ".
Same error appears if I try to install the guest using virt-install.
Don't know where to even begin looking for clues.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `<forward mode='bridge'/>`? This is intended for connecting to existing bridges not managed by libvirt, such as those provided by Open vSwitch. It probably is not what you want.

Comment: It really doesn't matter what I define, this was just an example and the bridge did exist. I've tried several other network types. Even if I type virus net-list I get this error.

Comment: The next obvious question is, what hypervisor are you connecting to?

Comment: KVM on a gentoo fresh install. I ventured into gentoo which I am a total beginner at but I will hold off for now and stick with ubuntu. Thanks for helping out.